# PHP OOPS extends class a,b,c,a1 issue

Tags: php, oop

I have the below listed classes

`1. Software_Base
 2. User Login
 3. Basic Function
 4. User Logout`

what i wanted to do is i need to access a child class method in another child class. but which is not inter connected with **extends**

My class extends looks like below

1. Software Base

   2. User Login

      3. User Logout
2. Basic function

`

```
  class base_class {

    public function __construct(){
        $this->init_class();
    }

    public function init_class(){
        $this->user_login = new user_login;
        $this->base_functions = new base_functions; 
    }

    public function value_from_Base_class(){
        return 'Value From Base Class';
    }

}

class user_login extends base_class {
    public function __construct(){
        var_dump($this->value_from_Base_class());  # Works :) 
    }

    public function value_from_user_login_class(){
        return 'Value From User Login Class';
    }
}


class user_logout extends user_login {
    public function __construct(){
        var_dump($this->value_from_Base_class());  # Works :) 
        var_dump($this->value_from_user_login_class());  # Works :) 
    }

}


class base_functions extends base_class{ 
    public function __construct(){
        var_dump($this->value_from_Base_class());  # Not Works :(
        var_dump($this->value_from_user_login_class());  # Not Works :(
    }
}
```

`

Comment: if you want to call `value_from_user_login_class()` in your `base_function` class then this function must exists in either `base_function` class or the parent class. Other wise it wont work.
alternate way: you can extend `user_login` in your  `base_functions` class

Comment: @ChetanAmeta i tried the same but its not working :(

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Call to undefined function..

Comment: this is because function do not exists in current or parent class

Comment: what is oops? object-oriented programming *secure*?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier. yes its 100% secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject an `user_login` instance when contructing `base_functions`:

```
class base_functions extends base_class{
    public function __construct($user_login){
        var_dump($this->value_from_Base_class());
        var_dump($user_login->value_from_user_login_class());
    }
}
$f = new base_functions(new user_login());
```

The call to `$this->value_from_Base_class()` in `base_functions` should work anyway.

Comment: sorry i should not do like that i am using in wordpress.. so this is not possible for me.